# My Function that rolls basic values for abilities on a character sheet does not change anything

Tags: javascript, html, css

My top button is supposed to execute the **roll()** function which "rolls" the starting Ability Scores for the character (3d6 for each attribute). But instead of filling the inputs in the right hand table, It simply refreshes the page.
I tried moving the JS to an internal script on my HTML page, but I had the same issue, so I assume the issue is within my JavaScript code itself, but I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work.

```js
/* 
 * roll() takes dice and does base scores
 * calculate() fills in ability modifiers
 * ac() updates AC as armor bon and shield bon are changed
 */
function roll() {
  First Base ability scores
  var Strength = die(3, 6);
  var Dexterity = die(3, 6);
  var Constitution = die(3, 6);
  var Intelligence = die(3, 6);
  var Wisdom = die(3, 6);
  var Charisma = die(3, 6);
  document.getElementById("str").value = Strength;
  document.getElementById("dex").value = Dexterity;
  document.getElementById("con").value = Constitution;
  document.getElementById("int").value = Intelligence;
  document.getElementById("wis").value = Wisdom;
  document.getElementById("cha").value = Charisma;
}

function die(times, sides) {
  var total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    total += Math.floor(Math.random() * sides) + 1;
  }
  return total;
}
```

```css
* {
  border: solid 0px black;
}
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 700px;
  font-family: "Bodoni MT", Didot, "Didot LT STD", "Hoefler Text", Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;
  text-align: center;
  3 height: 700px;
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Papyrus, fantasy;
}
form input {} input[type=text] {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
fieldset {
  height: 600px;
}
label {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
hr {
  min-width: 450px;
  size: 2px;
  color: black;
}
#leftT {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
}
#rightT {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
#rightT table {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
}
#leftT table {
  margin-left: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#rightT input {
  width: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 2.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#leftT input[type="calced"] {
  width: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 2.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
td[id="ab"] {
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
#leftT input[type="armorbo"] {
  width: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 2.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#leftT p {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
}
td {} label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
select {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: black;
  background-color: #704420;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 3px groove #8b4500;
  font-weight: bold;
}
button:active {
  background-color: #8b4500;
  border: 3px groove #704420;
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Pathfinder Char Gen</TITLE>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="charStyle.css" />
  <script src="char.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="title">Pathfinder : Character Creator</div>
    <hr>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="playerName">Enter Player Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="playerName">
        <br/>
        <label for="charName">Enter Character Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="charName">
        <br/>
        <label for="class">Select Character Class:</label>
        <select name="class" id="classes">
          <option id="cleric">Cleric</option>
          <option id="fighter">Fighter</option>
          <option id="sorcerer">Sorcerer</option>
        </select>
        <label for="level">Select Level:</label>
        <select name="level" id="cLevel">
          <option id="one">1</option>
          <option id="two">2</option>
          <option id="three">3</option>
          <option id="four">4</option>
          <option id="five">5</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <label for="align">Choose Your Alignment:</label>
        <select name="align" id="alignment">
          <option id="lawG">Lawful Good</option>
          <option id="caoG">Chaotic Good</option>
          <option id="neuG">Neutral Good</option>
          <option id="neutral">True Neutral</option>
          <option id="lawE">Lawful Evil</option>
          <option id="caoE">Chaotic Evil</option>
          <option id="neuE">Neutral Evil</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <button id="rolls" onclick="roll()">Roll</button>
        <br/>
        <div id="leftT">

          <table>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>Fortitude:</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input readonly type="calced" id="fortitude">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>Reflex:</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input readonly type="calced" id="reflex">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>Will:</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input readonly type="calced" id="will">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>HP:</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input readonly type="calced" id="hp">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Armor Bonus</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Shield Bonus</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>AC:</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input readonly type="calced" id="ac">
              </td>
              <td>
                =
              </td>
              <td height="10px">
                10
              </td>
              <td>
                +
              </td>
              <td>
                <input onchange="ac()" type="armorbo" id="ab">
              </td>
              <td>
                +
              </td>
              <td>
                <input onchange="ac()" type="armorbo" id="ab">
              </td>
              <td>
                +
              </td>
              <td>
                <input readonly type="calced" id="dexB">
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">BAB:</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input readonly type="calced" id="reflex">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p style="margin-bottom:5px;">CMB:</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input readonly type="calced" id="will">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>CMD:</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input readonly type="calced" id="will">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="rightT">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td>
                Score
              </td>
              <td id="ab">
                Ability Mod.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                STR
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="str" id="str">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="strB" id="strB">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                DEX
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="dex" id="dex">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="dexB" id="dexB">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CON
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="con" id="con">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="conB" id="conB">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                INT
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="int" id="int">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="intB" id="intB">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                WIS
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="wis" id="wis">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="wisB" id="wisB">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CHA
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="cha" id="cha">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="chaB" id="chaB">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <button id="calc" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Please Help!

Comment: If you took the time to open up the browser debug tools, you'd see syntax errors in the console.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiar with the browser's debugging tools, if someone could please explain where I can find them and how to use them, I will be very grateful.

Comment: It seems you figured out on your own, but for reference, dev tools or the console open with F12 in IE, CTRL+J in chrome or CTRL+SHIFT+K in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I just had incorrect syntax in my for loop... I fixed it after looking closer at the console and doing some snooping.